# How can I change count of a Collection Fieldset in Zend Form when using Annotations?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-framework3, zend-form2

From https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-form/quick-start/#using-annotations:

Via using `Zend\Form\Annotation`, I can issue this directive:

```
/**
 * @ComposedObject({
 *     "target_object":"Namespace\Model\ComposedCollection",
 *         "is_collection":"true",
 *         "options":{"count":2}
 *     }); 
 */
private $property;
```

What this does is create a collection of `ComposedCollection` elements, in the above case, of size `2`.

It's great when I need a static form with 2 elements, but how do I change it when I want to alter it dynamically?  i.e. internally I want to be able to populate the form with 4 or 5 sets of data, with the number being unknown ahead of time.

Using Annotations is static, and not dynamic.  Is there any way to do this?

I have tried using

```
$form->get("element_name")->setOption("count", $numericValue);
```

but it does not work, because I am guessing by the time I am using it, the form has already been built by the Annotation engine (`$annotationBuilder->createForm(MyEntity::class);`

Is there a way to rebuild the form?

I have tried `$form->prepare()`

but it only actually removes my Collection elements instead.

I have also tried `$form->init()` but it appears to do nothing.

I am in the process of rewriting the form NOT using Annotations, but that's not what I am trying to accomplish, since I am effectively losing my Entity by rewriting it in a programmatic way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Collection::setCount()` method.

```
$form->get("element_name")->setCount($numericValue);
```

Also, as an alternative you can define fieldset programmatically.  Place `@Annotation\Exclude()` on the `$property` and create a Fieldset like so:

```
    $c = new Element\Collection('collection');
    $c->setOptions([
        'label' => 'Collection',
        'count' => 1    ,
        'should_create_template' => true,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'target_element' => [
            'type' => ComposedCollectionFieldset::class
        ]
    ]);
```

Where `ComposedCollectionFieldset` contains the `Elements` that you need.